# Global solution for small data in H^1 for Schrodinguer equation focusing case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have the Schrodinguer´s equation in the focusing case and I need to prove that for data small enough in $H^1$ the solution that we know that exists it is global on time.I guess that could be using Lyapunov estability and seeing that 0 is estable but I do not know how to prove it.

$u_t = i (\Delta u + u |u|^\alpha)$, $ \alpha>1$, $x\in R^N $

$u(x,0)= \phi /x)$

I need to prove the existence of global solution for all $1<\alpha<\frac{N-2}{N+1} $ when data $\phi$ is enough small in $H^1$

Comment: Sure. Sorry I am new on this page

Comment: I have just changued the problem. You can see it now. Thank you.